# Laravel - Unable to catch Tymon JWT TokenInvalidException

Tags: php, laravel-5, exception, jwt

I am creating an API using Laravel 5.4 framework. Using JWT token, I am however unable to catch the InvalidTokenException when I input a wrong token. Please see my code and advice. Thank you!

```
    $token = $request->token;
    try{
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
    }catch(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){     //NOT CATCHING...
        $error = 'Invalid token';
        return response()->json(compact('error'));
    }
```

Comment: Is it the right namespace for the exception

Comment: @DestinatioN yes, it is the right namespace. Have googled and got the same results about catching the exception

Comment: Maybe you imported the exception so you could remove everything except the name of the exception

Comment: @DestinatioN have actually tried (TokenInvalidException $e), it wasnt catching still though.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably throwing a different exception then the one you are trying to catch.
Try to catch it using any exception, and see if this works. If so, the namespace is most likely incorrect.

```
  $token = $request->token;
  try{
      $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
  }catch(\Exception $e){    
    $error = 'Invalid token';
    return response()->json(compact('error'));
  }
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, despite using a general Exception, I'm still unable to catch it. That is indeed really strange

Comment: That's strange. Are you 100% sure the exception is thrown at that spot? Not somewhere else in the code?